# Como deixar o texto alinhado no responsivo?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Gente estou fazendo o site politicadascidades.com.br e quando mudo para o design responsivo me deparo com isso

Essa é a tela de bem vindo em versão desktop, o texto está com align="center" e tudo ok conforme pedido. Porém na versão responsiva o texto ficou muito esquisito e a imagem "Bem Vindo" diminuiu como na imagem abaixo dessa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na versão responsiva o texto perdeu a qualidade como podem ver, alguém poderia me explicar o motivo?

Não sei se pelo F12 consegue mas o site é politicadascidades.com.br

Comment: seu problema está aqui... @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
style.css:376
.bemvindo {
    margin: 125px 120px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere a `margin` no seu `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)` para um valor menor.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
/* style.css:376 */

.bemvindo {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Descoberto assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa cara muito obrigado!